# Label not changing after extracting data from SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, forms

[image: Form]

The User label after the Dear User will change accordingly to the user currently logged in , through the code from `lblcName.Text = detail;`

and i've create a code for the iCount , Viewer and Time to change based on the User logged in , getting the User data and display it here. but the Label didnt change.. anywhere in this code i might do wrong?

debugging by putting `breakpoint` on `DataRow firstRow = dtC.Rows[0];` shows that my `label` for `iCount` value is 1 , but did not change the value , and the `viewer` and `time` `label` value is also Viewer and Time

```
public partial class Notification : Form
    {
        public Notification(string detail)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblcName.Text = detail;
        }

        private void Notification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dtC = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter daCount = new SqlDataAdapter("select iCount,LastView,Viewtime from ComDet where cName = @cName", conn);
            daCount.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblcName.Text;

            daCount.Fill(dtC);
            DataRow firstRow = dtC.Rows[0];

            lblCount.Text = firstRow["iCount"].ToString();
            lblLastView.Text = firstRow["LastView"].ToString();
            lblView.Text = firstRow["ViewTime"].ToString();
conn.Close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually showing the form that's done the loading?

Comment: yes.. this was after a button was click to show the form , but the label did not change..

Comment: Probably it is not related at all, but do you really have this table in the database `master`? If yes not a good idea.

Comment: It sounds like you should show us more code... you haven't really provided enough context here. (You should use a `using` statement for the connection, by the way.)

Comment: What happens if you change the label to some literal value, like "this is different"?

Comment: @JonSkeet - i'll edit my question then..

Comment: @JohnSaunders - meaning?

Comment: @Steve - yes i have the database in master , someone did explained that it isnt a good idea , but i am doing this just for my friday presentation , and this isnt a problem , not publishing this anyway..

Comment: As a troubleshooting technique, try `lblView.Text = "something different";` then see if it gets set. If it does, then the label _can_ be set, and the problem is your data

Comment: ok , setting it now.. be back in a sec..

Comment: hei , you're right , it didnt even change.. why is that?

Comment: if i put lblLastView.Text = "Something different"; on top of my string connection string , the label changed , but when i put it after the datarow , nothing's changed.

Comment: I can't see your code, so this is only a guess: the data in the database is setting the label to an empty value? I really don't quite get it. How are you calling the form? `Notification n = new Notification("detail"); n.Show();`?

Comment: No , the Data in the database for iCount , LastView and ViewTime is different for different users. So the data in the database should be setting the label to be the same value as the data.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - but then, i am calling it by `private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _notif = new Notification(txtUser2.Text);
            _notif.ShowDialog();
        }`

Comment: @JohnSaunders - i have another form that have the same code , and it worked there , the other form is to extract all the data from database to a label.

so i thought the code will work on another form , but it didnt.

Comment: is there somewhere i can show u the code of the other form , and to compare with this form?

Comment: i have 2 forms working with the code , but not with this form..

Comment: @JohnSaunders - i've just tried this. i copied `lblCount.Text = firstRow["iCount"].ToString();` to the other form , and the code works there.. but still didnt work in this form.

Comment: I don't think we're going to be able to figure it out by looking. Have you tried running the code in the debugger and single stepping?

Comment: just did.. a friend came in , and i showed him the code , he said "isnt this suppose to show this?" (in reference) , then i was like ,owh.. ya... so.. this is a bad question actually as i had the wrong data. The Data i need is indeed in ComDet , but the reference i am using `"cName"` doesn't refer to that table. i'll make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the database is not empty. Second, Use the Validate() method of the form that refreshes the form's controls.

Comment: Ok, what about calling the Validate() method? Try calling the method Update() as well (after validate).

Comment: i had the wrong table reference.. the data i need is indeed in dbo.ComDet , but i was using cName from another table which is dbo.cID.